# How to use parameterized methods for hooks - SpecFlow

Tags: c#, bdd, specflow

In our project we have multiple SKUs differentiated by SKU id. We are testing different scenarios where SKUs are added to database. After each scenario clean up should happen in Db to delete the SKUs added by that particular scenario with `AfterScenario` hook. The cleanup method shoud receive the SKU Ids added by each scenario so that it will delete only those data. How to pass parameter to the clean up method tagged by `AfterScenario`(sample of requirement given below).

```
  [AfterScenario]
  public void Cleanup(string skuId)
  {
      //delete skuId from Db.
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be better to keep track of the SKUs each scenario creates by putting them in the ScenarioContext. You can get a reference to this as a constructor parameter to your step definitions. Then you can access it in your hooks and delete them:

```
public class SkuSteps
{
    private readonly ScenarioContext scenario;
    
    public SkuSteps(ScenarioContext scenario)
    {
        this.scenario = scenario;
    }
    
    [Given(@"a sku named ""(.*)"" exists")]
    public void GivenASkuNamedExists(string sku)
    {
        // create sku
        scenario.AddSku(sku);
    }
}

public static class ScenarioExtensions
{
    public static void AddSku(this ScenarioContext scenario, string sku)
    {
        var skus = scenario.GetSkus();
        
        skus.Add(sku);
    }
    
    public static List<string> GetSkus()
    {
        if (!scenario.ContainsKey("skus"))
        {
            scenario["skus"] = new List<string>();
        }
        
        return (List<string>)scenario["skus"];
    }
}
        
public class Hooks
{
    private readonly ScenarioContext scenario;

    public Hooks(ScenarioContext scenario)
    {
        this.scenario = scenario;
    }

    [AfterScenario]
    public void DeleteSkus()
    {
        var skusToDelete = scenario.GetSkus();
        
        // delete the skus
    }
}
```

Comment: Good way to solve the question! Only thing I would do is to save the SKUs in a typesafe class and get it via Context- Injection (https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Bindings/Sharing-Data-between-Bindings.html#context-injection) then using the Dictionary<string, object> on the ScenarioContext.